# Good practices for initing variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a colleague that instantiates all his variables with empty string for their default value. That variable later could have an array or object assigned to it an although that might be known he still assigns empty string as default. Ex.

```
function getAllCars(){
  var listOfCars = ['bmw','fiat','reno'];
  return listOfCars;
}

function getAnyCar(){
  var cars = "";
  cars = getAllCars();
  var car = cars.slice(0,1);
  return car;
}
```

TL;DR:
What should a good practice for defining `cars` be

1. `var cars;`
2. `var cars = [];`
3. `var cars = "";`

I am trying to explain to him that if you know that the variable `cars` is going to be used to hold an array you should define it with an empty array.

He argues that he knows that variable is 100% going to be assigned an array down the line i.e `cars = getAllCars();` so it doesn't matter. In a small function such a thing may be visible but I believe it to be bad practice.

Comment: The better practice would be never have uninitialized objects in your code and generally do `const cars = getAllCars()`. Dealing with unclean state is [pretty hard](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). This is subjective though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the talk that you linked. Seems interesting. Will save it to watch later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is dynamically typed and allows changing type at run-time, but this makes your code confusing.

According to good practices (if not best), it's suggested to initialize variable when declaring it. This gives cleaner code (clear indication that cars is an array) and avoids `undefined` values.

```
var cars = [];
```

On the other hand, some devs prefer to just declare and not initialize until necessary. So this is also fine.

```
var cars;
```

I think which one to follow of these two is matter of opinion or perhaps choice. But for sure, initializing `var cars = ""` does not make sense at all in your example.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed bad practice to have a variable change its type often to unrelated types. Javascript already has *two* perfectly fine values to mean "no value": `undefined` and `null`. What you read into the difference is mostly up to you, but both are much more appropriate than an empty string. The mostly natural way would be the default `undefined`:

```
var cars;
```

This reserves the variable name in the scope, but does not assign it a value. That is the clearest way to express what this code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an empty string as a default value is a pretty bad practice. I would use

```
var cars = getAllCars();
```